# Phone can not reset and cannot boot to recovery mode

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, factory-reset

Actually I don't know what I did or did not do. I'm running a stock jellybean ROM. It is rooted. I've tried to soft reset the device but when I hit the "delete everything" in factory reset, the phone reboots normally and my apps are still there looking at me with their data.
Secondly, when I try to perform a hard reset, phone won't boot into recovery mode not even when I use adb or terminal Emulator, or hardware buttons or other advanced reboot apps. But the device can enter fast boot mode.
Any idea what is wrong??